# Exchange mailbox archiving via Powershell to .pst file

Tags: powershell, exchange, archiving, shared-mailbox, mailbox

I'm in a particular situation in which I have to free up space on some mailboxes present on our exchange server, both regular and shared mailboxes.

I remember that years ago, via powershell, it was possible to use the Search-Mailbox command to export emails to a PST file.
Also there were some commands back in the day, that were limited to work with no more than 10,000 elements, is it still the case?
I need something that does the job regardless the number of elements (email messages) stored in a mailbox.

Now via the GUI on the compliance admin console, it is possible to create a new content search and export the results into a PST file as well and if I'm not mistaken it does export everything recreating the basic mailbox folder structure, without recreating the structure which may have been created by the user, I believe it is the equivalent of doing a New-MailboxExportRequest via powershell.

I am familiar with the GUI as I have already used this to create PST files of entire mailboxes before removing them permanently from exchange.

Having said that, what I need to set up is a short script via powershell which would allow me to:

1)Archive a specific mailbox, allowing me to archive the elements older than (ex. 01/01/2019), to a local or network storage.

2)Delete all those elements older than the date specified in the export, in order to free up space for the mailbox on the exchange server.

Would the combination of New-MailboxExportRequest and Search-Mailbox do the trick?

I was thinking of exporting the elements first with the New-MailboxExportRequest and after doing that, just delete those elements with Search-Mailbox -identity  -searchquery {received:mm/dd/yyyy..mm/dd/yyyy} -deletecontent

I was searching for a similar solution here, but have found nothing.
I'm looking forward to see your suggestions as this is a tedious task which I have to do manually all the time, having more than 1000 mailboxes in our company.

EDIT: Just to be clear, the Search-Mailbox command should be already deprecated for the cloud environment, can my request be adapted to New-ComplianceSearch?

Comment: Yes, you can technically do this with compliance searches, but there are many limitations making it harder to do for many mailboxes. One of the main ones is you cannot download the final PST using powershell - it must be done through the console. Other limitations here, like 10 searches at a time: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/limits-for-content-search . You can quickly delete stuff using a compliance search's `-purge` option

Comment: Thanks for the info @Cpt.Whale
I guess that Microsoft deprecated certain commands in order to make it more difficult, while replacing the deprecated commands with newer ones which are less effective.
In my case a combination of compliance search to first export the desired elements and another compliance search afterwards to delete those specific elements, should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

According to your request, I believe the blog may be helpful to your issue. For more details: [Export Microsoft 365 mailboxes to PST with PowerShell](https://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/export-microsoft-365-mailboxes-to-pst-powershell/)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I described.
I have already tested the compliance search via powershell and via gui, as someone commented on my main question, it has its limitations.
Your suggestions does not solve my issue however.

I wanted to create a script to first export a PST archive and afterwards erase all those exported elements from the mailbox, in order to free up space.

It seems that Microsoft might have purposely deprecated the Search-Mailbox command to force users to buy E3 licences, as it comes with unilimited archiving space.

Comment: I still have Search-Mailbox available to me. Not sure about deprecation.